# ftp_mkdir creates 2 folders

Tags: php, ftp, directory, timestamp

I created this simple PHP script to store files under a folder created using a timestamp, but the script is creating 2 folders instead of one.

```
$connection = ftp_connect($server);

$login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }

$timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

ftp_mkdir($connection, $timestamp);

$upload = ftp_put($connection, "./".$timestamp."/".$dest, $source, FTP_BINARY );

if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

ftp_close($connection);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try escaping the spaces in the $timestamp variable.

Comment: no, it's just to create only one folder using a timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Since your directory naming logic uses a timestamp, you could be running into a condition where the system is simply running your FTP logic twice when uploading? Or something along those lines. So try wrapping your [`ftp_mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mkdir.php) command with directory check logic using [`ftp_chdir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php) so the directory is only created if it doesn’t already exist:

```
if (!@ftp_chdir($connection, $timestamp)) {
  ftp_mkdir($connection, $timestamp);
}
```

So the whole thing would now read as:

```
$connection = ftp_connect($server);

$login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }

$timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

if (!@ftp_chdir($connection, $timestamp)) {
  ftp_mkdir($connection, $timestamp);
}

$upload = ftp_put($connection, "./".$timestamp."/".$dest, $source, FTP_BINARY );

if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

ftp_close($connection);
```

**EDIT:** Another idea is to just comment out the line that has the `ftp_mkdir` and see what happens:

```
# ftp_mkdir($connection, $timestamp);
```

Comment: I tried you solution, but it continues creating 2 folders and I just want one. In one folder it puts the file ($source) and the other one is empty, I don't know why.

Comment: any folder is created then